# Why does the chart disappear when I copy the excel file?

Tags: php, excel

With PHPExcel 1.6.7, i tried to clone a excel file, insert a word in a cell of sheet1 of new file and then save it :

```
$file = "file.xls";
$fp = fopen($file, "r"); 
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
$xls = $objReader->load($file);
//$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0) ;

$xls->getSheetByName('sheet1')->setCellValue('A2', 'bbb') ;

$newxls = clone $xls ;

$newfile = "newfile.xls" ;
$xlsfile = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($newxls);
$xlsfile->save($newfile);
```

The problem is : there should be a chart in sheet2, but the chart disappeared in the new file (as i just modified the sheet1)

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

PHPExcel does not currently support charts so charts will not be saved if you open a document with charts. For a workaround try the method [described here (only works with xlsx)](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=48411)